# Problems with wp_editor in plugin admin page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add the wordpress editor to the admin page of a plugin I am building using this code:

```
$editor_id = "mailbody";
$content = "hello";
$settings = array( 'textarea_name' => 'mailbody' );

wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

While the code is returning a instance of the editor to the plugin admin page non of the buttons are showing, the tabs are not working & media buttons are not working.
In the console I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: switchEditors is not defined, when clicking on the visual/text tabs.

Any ideas to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with this problem look here:
http://www.presscoders.com/2011/11/how-to-reuse-the-post-editor-in-wordpress-3-3/

My problem was being caused by a misplaced exit in the template "blank plugin" found here: http://graemewilson.co.nz/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-blank-plugin/